# Entity Exception в ActionResult Index

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, исключения

Здравствуйте, интересовался как можно работать с изображениями в Asp .Net и что меня интересовало,  это как можно реализовать CRUD функционал с несколькими изображениями . Чтобы мы например загрузили 3 изображения сразу в БД  и потом могли либо удалить их,  либо добавить програмно. (некая галерея чтобы можно было ей управлять) Вот я наткнулся на похожее приложение http://techbrij.com/crud-file-upload-asp-net-mvc-ef-multiple. но этот код не срабатывает и выбивает Entity Exception : Исключение типа "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException" возникло в EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя

Дополнительные сведения: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Я пытался сменить в WeBConfig строку подключения , это не помогло. Так же лез в диспетчер служб IIS в пулы приложений и там менял на LocalSystem но и это не помогло. Вот метод на котором выбивает ошибка:

```
public class SupportController : Controller
    {
        private SupportContext db = new SupportContext();

        //
        // GET: /Support/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Supports.ToList());
        }
```

Вот полный стек Exception:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\file-upload-crud-asp-net-mvc-master\file-upload-crud-asp-net-mvc-master\MultipleFileUpload\App_Data\aspnet-MVC4Drop.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +830
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +329
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +682
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2() +55
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +253

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +323
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions) +133
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +46
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +155
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +281
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   MultipleFileUpload.Controllers.SupportController.Index() in D:\file-upload-crud-asp-net-mvc-master\file-upload-crud-asp-net-mvc-master\MultipleFileUpload\Controllers\SupportController.cs:22
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9644037
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: я вот что заметил что оно также ругается на то что файл БД отсутствует в папку App_Data, но я думал что EF  его сам сформирует

Comment: возможно дело в строке поключения

Comment: @Ruslan_K я тоже думаю , но я её уже столько раз менял и всё без смысла, сама строка вот: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVC4Drop-20150918165325;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVC4Drop-20150918165325.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings> я пробовал убрать Integration Sercurity , Initial Catalog , всё бессмысленно , тот же Exception . может вы что порекомендуете??

Answer (score 0):

Проблема описана в самом тексте ошибки: в вашем экземпляре Sql Server уже есть подключенная база данных с таким же именем. Все базы данных подключаются к экземпляру Sql Server на вашем компьютере, при этом не может быть двух баз данных с одним именем.

Чтобы найти и отключить дублирующие базы данных, рекомендую открыть Sql Server Management Studio ([установить](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299), если её ещё нет) и подключиться к экземпляру (LocalDb)\v11.0. В левой части раскрыть список баз данных, найти базу данных с таким же именем и в контекстном меню в пункте "Задачи" нажать "Отсоединить".